# C# convert ISO-8859-1 characters to entity number

Tags: c#, encode, iso-8859-1

I can't seem to figure out how to convert ISO-8859-1 characters, such as é, to it's entity number being `&#233;`.

I want to be able to take a string, such as: "Steel Décor"

and have it converted to: "Steel D`&#233;`cor"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about HTML-encoding characters that are special in HTML (e.g., <, &, etc.), a simple loop over the string will work:

```
string input = "Steel Décor";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char ch in input)
{
    if (ch > 0x7F)
        output.AppendFormat("&#{0};", (int) ch);
    else
        output.Append(ch);
}
// output.ToString() == "Steel D&#233;cor"
```

The `if` statement may need to be changed to also escape characters `< 0x20`, or non-alphanumeric, etc., depending on your exact needs.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` does that. It resides in System.Web.dll though so won't work with .NET 4 Client Profile for example.

Comment: It does and it doesn't. It encodes the string, but not in the text format i'm looking for. It was the first thing i tried. I'm also not working with web stuff.

Answer (score 1):

using LINQ

```
string toDec(string input)
{
    Dictionary<string, char> resDec =
        (from p in input.ToCharArray() where p > 127 select p).Distinct().ToDictionary(
            p => String.Format(@"&#x{0:D};", (ushort)p));

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, char> pair in resDec)
        input = input.Replace(pair.Value.ToString(), pair.Key);
    return input;
}
```