# Encode - C# convert ISO-8859-1 entities number to characters

Tags: c#

I found a question about how to convert ISO-8859-1 characters to entity number 
[C# convert ISO-8859-1 characters to entity number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278371/c-sharp-convert-iso-8859-1-characters-to-entity-number)
code:

```
string input = "Steel Décor";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char ch in input)
{
    if (ch > 0x7F)
    output.AppendFormat("&#{0};", (int) ch);
else
    output.Append(ch);
}
// output.ToString() == "Steel D&#233;cor"
```

but i didn't figure out how to do the opposite converting from entity number to character like from 
`//"Steel D&#233;cor" to "Steel Décor"`

ps: all accent character in my string are entity code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .NET how to convert ISO 8859-1 encoded text files that contain Latin-1 accented characters to UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595442/using-net-how-to-convert-iso-8859-1-encoded-text-files-that-contain-latin-1-acc)

Comment: With regular expressions? Just capture all `&#nnn` and replace.

Comment: What you mean exactly by regular expressions ? any code explications ?